# What class name should I use for an Adapter Pattern adaptor?

Tags: adapter, naming

Let's assume I've got a class SomethingDAO which I need to adapt to an interface SomethingProvider.

What should I call the adapter class?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`SomethingDaoToProviderAdapter` or `SomethingProviderToDaoAdapter` seems clear to me and I would suggest this.